# How to use backtick to call function on click

Tags: javascript, html, template-literals

trying to use backtick but it calls the function on-load. validateRequest() function should call on click of button

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

function validateRequest(){
    alert("");
}

const markUp = `<button onclick="${validateRequest()}">Click me</button>`;

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = markUp;

</script>
```

Comment: Once you use `validateRequest()` to assign it in this way, it will be executed and the function result will be added to `onclick` event which is `undefined`. Instead try as `onclick="validateRequest()"`.

Comment: that would call validateRequest, and insert the returned valued (undefined) into the HTML - not sure why you'd want to use such a pattern to be honest

Comment: eslint produces no-unused-vars when using it in a string template. @norbitrial

Answer (score 1):

As I have mentioned in the comment section, once you use with template literals in that way `validateRequest` function will be evaluated which means it will return `undefined`. Thus `undefined` will be added to `onclick` event which won't have any effect once you click the button in your screen.

Based on my understanding once you do the suggested way to use `onclick="validateRequest()"` instead you get an `no-unused-vars` warning from ESLint.

Instead you could try as the following:

```js
const validateRequest = () => alert("I'm working");
const button = document.createElement('button');
button.onclick = validateRequest;
button.innerHTML = 'Click me';

document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(button);
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Backtick or template literals uses "interpolation" to insert variables. Thus, 
 your code:

```
const markUp = `<button onclick="${validateRequest()}">Click me</button>`;
```

after interpolation

```
const markUp = `<button onclick="undefined">Click me</button>`;
```

**How to fix this??**
~ It's simple, just remove the place holder *`${}`* .
Below is the working code:

```
 const markUp = `<button onclick="validateRequest()">Click me</button>`;
```

Comment: Do you see any solution for `no-unused-vars` **ESLint** warning once you use in that way the `onclick` assignment? I have suggested that solution in the comment section but OP has pointed out that warning. Just interested.

Comment: hi, I have verified the above code and it  is working fine. As far I know, no-unused-vars ESLint warning is {not related to template literal}. It would have come, even if we have used tradition double quote or single quote notation in the {ES Lint}. In order to remove the warning, we need to call the function validateRequest(),in plain javascript. Check out this link: https://eslint.org/docs/2.0.0/rules/no-unused-vars

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to mention ${} while calling the function in the onclick attribute, if you can define your problem then I might could help :)

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

function validateRequest(){
    alert("");
}

const markUp = `<button onclick="validateRequest()">Click me</button>`;

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = markUp;

</script>
```